# ParseImageView on Android not displaying image

Tags: java, android, web-services, parse-platform, imageview

I am having a strange problem with the ParseImageView. I have a ParseImageView defined in my layout:

```
    <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and I am calling the method:

```
imageView = (ParseImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view1_imageview);
```

to initialize the imageView.

But when I call:

```
     pff = (ParseFile) object.get("favimg");
     Log.d("ParseFile",pff.toString());
     imageView.setParseFile(pff);
```

the image view is not set. I have confirmed that the ParseFile pff is set. 
Any pointers are appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use loadInBackground()  to actually fetch the file:

```
  imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                // nothing to do
                if (e != null)
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
```